# Add and Subtract multiple element of numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

Hi I have a python code as:

```
import numpy as np     
a = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]])
b = a[0,1]+a[2,2]-a[1,1]
>>> b
>>> 6
```

Is there any other faster way to add/subtract a list of specific elements of an array?

Comment: Look here: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/routines.array-manipulation.html#adding-and-removing-elements

Comment: Not sure I understand the question. Is there a faster way to add two specific elements of an array together? No. Is there a faster way to add multiple of elements of an array together? Yes. Can you explain what you are trying to do a bit more?

Comment: The question is unclear. If you had a series of indices you may use `numpy.sum` for fast masking and addition on multi-dimensional arrays.

Comment: @MrE: I need to add and subtract multiple elements of an array together like a[0,1]+a[2,2]-a[1,1] to get some value.

Comment: @Developer: I have the series of indices but I need to add and subtract multiple elements. In that case numpy.sum won't help me.

Comment: @user2766019 add example/sample data with the series of indices to your question and we can show you how to get the result quickly with NumPy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you simply want to retrieve the values in an array from a list of indices, and sum them, you can do:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]])
ind = [[0,1],[2,2],[1,1]]
values = a[zip(*ind)]
b = values.sum()
# b = 2+9+5 = 16
```

Note that I set indices `ind` as a list of indices pairs, and thus `zip` is necessary. Obviously this can be done in multiple ways. `a[...]` just needs to get a list or tuple (not numpy array) of indices grouped by axis, i.e. `a[(0,2,1),(1,2,1)]`.

Now to make arbitrary addition or subtraction, there are multiple ways possible. For example:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]])
ind = [[0,1],[2,2],[1,1]]   # indices in array
op = [1,1,-1]               # 1 for addition, -1 for subtraction
values = a[zip(*ind)]*op
b = values.sum()
# b = 2+9-5 = 6
```

One last point: this method is useful for a set of indices of arbitrary size (i.e. which would be a parameter of your code). For 3 specific values, its is better to do it explicitly as in your code.